# Factoring binary quadratic form in two second order polynomials

Tags: polynomials, factoring, quadratic-forms

I have a binary quadratic form in $N$ and $D$, $AD^2 + BND + CN^2$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are real coefficients and $N$ is a second order polynomial of $x$ with real roots $\lvert r \rvert <1$ and $D$ is a second order polynomial of $x$ with real roots $\lvert r \rvert >1$. I want to factor this expression into the product of two second order polynomials of $x$ with **real** coefficients. I've solved this problem with complex coefficients - that isn't so hard - but I believe that factoring this quadratic form into the product of two second order polynomials of $x$ is a tractable problem!

A good answer will either:

1. Give a method for computing the coefficients of the two polynomials of $x$ (without relying on root finding of polynomials of order greater than 2).
2. Provide a proof that this problem is not, in general, tractable.

Comment: I solved this problem, I will post my answer later today.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the quadratic form using the quadratic formula but, in general, the roots will be complex. The monomials the quadratic form factors into will be in the form $(D+cN)$, so the polynomial of $x$ one gets by distributing $c$ into $N$ and adding $D$ will have complex coefficients. Since real coefficients are desired, the problem is not yet solved. However, I found that by factoring these complex polynomials, the roots can be matched with their complex conjugates and expanded back into second order polynomials, but now with real coefficients.

Comment: Keeping this open for now in case someone has a better answer.